# How do these types check for true equality between the parameters?

Tags: typescript, types

I feel the conditional types are very powerful.
I want to leverage it to do more complex and dynamic checking.

I want to check if given **2 generics are equal**.

I saw [this solution](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650) on Typescript's issues.

```js
type MyEquals<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) 
    ? true 
    : false

type res1 = MyEquals<true, false>                         // false, values
type res2 = MyEquals<true, true>                          // true,  values
type res3 = MyEquals<boolean, boolean>                    // true,  primitive types
type res4 = MyEquals<Promise<string>, Promise<string>>    // true,  advanced/custom types
```

I don't understand why the function `<T>() => T` notation and the primitives aren't functions so how is this type giving me a `true/false` on those values.

Can someone explain me how this `MyEquals` works and does it really work for all types?

[Another solution](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-931205995) stated in the same issue:

```js
type EqualsWrapped<T> = T extends infer R & {}
    ? {
          [P in keyof R]: R[P]
      }
    : never

export type Equals<A, B> = (<T>() => T extends EqualsWrapped<A> ? 1 : 2) extends
(<T>() => T extends EqualsWrapped<B> ? 1 : 2)
  ? true
  : false
```

Here I don't understand what does `T extends infer R & {}` actually do?
Isn't `extends` supposed to do a structural check `{a: string} == {a: number}`(resulting in false) kind of a check?
And infer is supposed to be used to target `Item` of an `Array` or `Property` of an `Object`, right? So what are we inferring here if `T` isn't a `Object` or `Array`?

Sorry for so many questions.